# Display multiple tables in datagrid

Tags: c#, entity-framework, select, join, datagrid

Hey I'm currently attempting to display multiple tables into a datagrid using c# and mysql, I've been looking at several different ways to do it and I believe the below should work but it doesnt produce any errors at all, I think I must be doing something wrong, any ideas? cheers

```
var query =
          from o in OfficeList()
          from s in StaffList()
          join d in ManagerList()
          on new { o.Office_ID, s.Staff_ID } equals new { Office_ID = d.office_Office_ID, Staff_ID = d.staff_Staff_ID } into details
          from d in details
          select new { o.Office_ID, o.Office_Name, d.staff_Staff_ID };



MessageBox.Show(query.Count().ToString());
office_Grid.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
```

Comment: We need some more information - what does it produce? You're showing the number of rows from the query in a MessageBox, how many does it say it returned? Assuming you're actually getting any records out of the query, does the DataGrid show any binding errors?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a winforms data grid view, you could use the DataSource property to bind. Since you seem to have a ItemsSource, what component are you using?

Comment: ItemsSource suggests it's a WPF DataGrid control.

Comment: yeah im currently using a wpf datagrid control

Answer (score 0):

```
office_Grid.DataSource= query.ToList();
office_Grid.DataBind();
```

this should work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111804/data-binding-a-wpf-datagrid-control-to-a-system-data-datatable-object